# How do compile mercurial from source on CentOS 5.8

Tags: python, mercurial, centos5

I want to compile mercurial (server) from source (version 2.2 as of now) on CentOS 5.8 against a compiled python2.6.

What are the steps?

Comment: did you attempt to read up the manual and come up short?

Comment: @ranamalo Searching google for `compile mercurial from source` yields mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/UnixInstall which details the steps nicely. Why not use google before asking on SO?

Comment: read that first of all and if you are stuck you could ask for help...

Comment: We also have a nice mailinglist: mercurial@selenic.com — lots of people will be happy to answer questions like this there.

Comment: @cobie.  This is not asking for help.  Sorry, didn't mean to confuse people.  I worked threw this issue on the irc with folks from the mercurial team and arrived at this solution.  I threw this up here as a help for others.  This was the suggestion in the mercurial irc channel. I asked if there was a wiki where I could throw these steps up to help others.  They said no, but why not make a question on stackoverflow and answer it.  Stackoverflow wouldn't let me answer my own question for 8 hours, so I just edited the question to include the solution.

Answer (score 0):

CentOS's default Python install of 2.4 works fine, so I ended up compiling mercurial against that, but given that I have another version installed (my python2.6 compiled version that is in /usr/local/bin and the default python, ie `which python` gives python2.6), there are some important steps to get this to work:

Download

```
cd /tmp
wget https://www.mercurial-scm.org/release/mercurial-2.2.tar.gz
tar xvzf mercurial-2.2.tar.gz
```

Compile and install

```
make all PYTHON='/usr/bin/python2.4'
make install PYTHON='/usr/bin/python2.4'
```

NOTE: make install basically runs:

```
python setup.py build
python setup.py  install --root="/" --prefix="/usr/local" --force
```

so it forces mercurial to install the libraries in /usr/local, it puts them in /usr/local/lib/python2.4/site-packages, so you must change something in hgwebdir.cgi

uncomment this:

```
#import sys
#sys.path.insert(0, "/path/to/python/lib")
```

and replace with this:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "/usr/local/lib/python2.4/site-packages")
```

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/10440165/2) to the question [How do compile mercurial from source on CentOS 5.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10440165/how-do-compile-mercurial-from-source-on-centos-5-8) by the OP [ranamalo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/756470/ranamalo) under CC BY-SA 3.0.</sub>